# Understanding Computer organisation and architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, books, digital-circuits

What are some of the books for "computer organisation and architechture" which are best for self study. Such a text that one can grasps the big picture, and understandhow various things are fitting with each other.

Topics include: machine instructions and addressing modes, ALU and data path , cpu control design, memory interface, I/o interface (interrupt and DMA mode), instruction pipelining, cache and main memory.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid this kind of question isn't a good fit for this site; asking for the best books is asking for a subjective recommendation, which doesn't work well on this site format.  See our [help/dont-ask].